# What sort of power socket is this?

Tags: identification, plug, socket

I am having trouble identifying the socket type of the power connection on an old voltmeter I purchased. It did not come with a cable, so I am trying to find a new one which will fit in the socket. It has two pins near the bottom of a circular hole, and a plastic ridge at the very bottom for alignment.

[image: The socket in question]

Comment: According to [here](http://annmaz2010.sklep2.pl/-p-1412.html) it's a Gniazdo MERA-ZEM 250V 6A Meratronik.

Comment: Soviet-era Eastern Europe?

Comment: If a plug cannot be obtained, it should be possible (with adequate dimensions) to design a 3D model of the plug, 3D print it, and slip in some terminals. Will require someone skilled in 3D printers and electronics.

Comment: Chances are a $10 voltmeter from Amazon is going to perform as well as this thing you got yourself here. Best of luck, the 3D printing option might be the easiest.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look radically different from a Bulgin 5A connector from the UK, 1950s/1960s era, e.g. [Nos 1,2 on this page](https://www.plugsocketmuseum.nl/Bulgin1.html), though without the ground pin. Often used on valve amplifiers, Leak and others.

Of course, without detailed dimensions, one can't be sure, but might be worth a closer look.

Comment: the missing ground pin can perhaps be explained by the "double insulation" symbol above the socket.